# Systems of equation with only 1 equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

So this is a system of equations problem only there's 1 equation as far as I could tell?

Roberto invested some money at 7% and then invested 2000 more than twice this amount at 10% His total anual income from the two investments was 2900 . How much was invested at 10%?

Equation: $2900 = 0.07x + 2(0.1y + 2000)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he invested $x$ money at $7\%$ and $y$ money at $10\%$, then we are told that $$2900=0.07x+0.1y$$ However, we're also told that $y=2x+2000$, two thousand more than twice $x$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it Arthur, I'm really bad at deriving equations from word problems.

Comment: @user3882522 No problem. It's an acquired skill that needs practice to get right. You'll get there eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: your equation is wrong. It should be

$$2900 = 0.07 x + 0.1(2x+2000).$$

Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, Arthur explained it to me, thank you for your answer though.